# Sendmail performance

Tags: email, sendmail

I have an ec2 micro instance running Centos on which I deploy my projects for testing purpose. Lately I developed a system which sends users email upon some events using sendmail. As I am the only one who use the system, the amount of emails sent per day is less than 50 and they are typically very simple emails.

After a few days I notice that the emails get delayed a lot after I issue send command, sometimes up to 15 minutes, and when they come, they come in batch (that is, several emails are delayed and then arrive at my inbox at one time). I understand there are reasons why we pay for email services like SES, but does sending email really take that much resources and why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your server have a fully-qualified domain name? Sendmail injects a delay when the sending host doesn't have a FQDN

To get one

```
first, in /etc/hostname, change your hostname from whatever to a FQDN like whatever.one-of-your-hosted-domain-names.com
then, in /etc/hosts, add a host entry like:

99.123.45.67 whatever.mysite.com
Reboot and try to send a mail to yourself again. Sendmail wil not delay at all.
```

Comment: yeah I think that's the reason, since it is just for testing purpose, I don't setup domain name.